# How to return the result of SpeechRecognizer in a method?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am making a speech-to-text android app and I have attached the source here. My problem is that, I have successfully converted the speech into text using `SpeechRecognizer` class. But when I call the `getResult()` method of my SpeechToText class then it gives

`java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int) on a null object reference`

The reason for error is that initially "results" is null `ArrayList` and it is initialize when `onResults()` method is called. Since the `getResult()` method is called before `onResults()`, the `ArrayList` results is **null**. So it gives error. But I want the `getResult()` method to return the result stored in ArrayList result. How to do that? By the way if I keep return type of `getResult() void` then the code runs correctly and toasts the output. But I want to return the output from `getResult()` instead of toasting it.

Please help.......

**SpeechToText.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SpeechToText{

private Context context;
private Intent intent;
private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private ArrayList<String> results;

public SpeechToText(Context c){
    this.context = c;

    intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle resultBundle) {
            results = new ArrayList(resultBundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION));
            Toast.makeText(context, results.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {}

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {}

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {}

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {}

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {}

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {}

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {}
    };

    recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
    recognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
}

public String getResult(){
    recognizer.startListening(intent);
    return results.get(0);
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    SpeechToText stt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stt = new SpeechToText(this);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stt.getResult(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can implement the listener in your MainActivity as an alternative. You got the solution or not??

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks @jankigadhiya.

Comment: Glad to know that.. Happy coding..!!